# While producing the messages, some brokers going breaking down makes any exception in Kafka producer side?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am testing the scenario as follows.
I am producing the messages to sink which is the Kafka containing the three brokers.
What if brokers are going to down, the producing side have an any issue because of the broker-down?

When I tested it on my local using Flink, I generated the messages and sinked them to Kafka. And I have three kafka brokers. When I deleted the number of brokers to 2, there are no problems. And obviously, when all the brokers are going to down, then the producer-side app gives an exception.

So, according to these fact, I think that the producer-side app can still alive without any errors until one broker remains. Is my assumption correct?

Below is the my producer side configuration.

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
compression.type = lz4
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
enable.idempotence = false
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
linger.ms = 0
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
```

replication is two and I have three partitions for each topic.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your requirements and your producer configuration. At the moment, yes you can have 2 out of 3 brokers alive and your producer will continue as normal.

This is because you have `acks=1` which means only the leader has to acknowledge the message before it is considered successful. The followers don't have to acknowledge the message.

You should also check whether you have changed `min.insync.replicas` at the broker or topic level configuration. The default is 1, meaning only 1 in-sync replica is needed for a broker to allow acks=all requests.

Side note: you have `replication=2`, I'd change this so partitions were replicated across all 3 brokers.

Comment: I confirm your recommendation Jessica, you're saying all :) .
But I think that @sclee1 asked about if the application hosting this producer if it stay a life even when loosing all kafka-brokers. But I agree that the question is not totally clear

Comment: Hi @ahmed.ettoumi I also agree with your answer, retries should be left as the default 2147483647.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but in Kafka client API there are some retryable Exceptions (like Not Leader, or unreached/unknown host).

So your Producer wil retry until reaching the first limit of these two configs:

- ***retries*** : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_retries
- ***delivery.timeout.ms*** : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_delivery.timeout.ms

So using the default values :
retries > **2 billions** time &
delivery.timeout.ms = **2 minutes**

Your producer will do **N** retries for only **2 minutes** then crashes.